# search a string in file and insert content above

Tags: java, seek, randomaccessfile

I try to search a string inside a txt-file and insert some specific content above it.
Sadly the output looks quite different from what I expect.
Can somebody give me a hint?

This is how far I got!

```
    String description= "filename.txt";
    String comparison="    return model;";
    RandomAccessFile output = null;
        try
        {
          output = new RandomAccessFile(description, "rw" );
          String line = null;
          while ((line = output.readLine()) != null) {
                  if (line.equals(comparison)){
                      //System.out.println("alt: "+line);
                      output.seek(output.getFilePointer()-line.getBytes().length);
                      output.writeChars("new stuff; \n");
                      //System.out.println("new: "+output.readLine());
                      }
          }
        }
        catch ( IOException e ) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {        
          if ( output != null ){ try { output.close(); } catch ( IOException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }}
        }
```

This is the file I try to read:

```
/*filename.txt*/
    some longer content ~ 100kB

    return model;

    further content
```

and this is what I hope to get

```
/*filename.txt*/
    some longer content ~ 100kB

    new stuff;

    return model;

    further content
```

Comment: And what do you actually get instead?

Comment: This is what you have, that is what you expect to get..but what are you getting?

Comment: Use two files. Copy until which line you want into a new file. Add your new line. Then again copy the rest of the lines into the file. At last, copy the whole content of the new file into the old file.

Comment: I get something i can't copy&paste in here because of encoding problems. Further it seems the writeChars command do overright values and do not insert them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files don't support insertion or deletion of content except at the end of the file. (It's not a limitation of Java but the OS)

To insert text, you must re-write the file (at the least from the point you want to alter) The simplest solution is to copy content to a temporary file, altering/inserting or deleting as required and replacing the original if this is sucessful.

Comment: I try to avoid building a copy because the filesize could became quite large.

Comment: Unless you are talking about 10 MB+ the size is unlikely to be important. In anycase, you can't do what you suggest.

Comment: [http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Appendingdatatoexistingfile.htm](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Appendingdatatoexistingfile.htm) In there the file is enlarged..... so it is possible?!

Comment: @user1193134 It is possible "at the end of the file", like I said.

Comment: So putting the parts "new stuff, return model and further content into a buffer and rewrite the end of the file will work?!

Comment: You can copy all the data down the file to create some space which you then use to add your text. This is much more compicated and not likely to give you much of a performance gain.  The main impact for smaller files ( < 10 MB) is the seek time which you incurr anyway.

Comment: @user1193134 Determine what your problem is and what the true cause is.  If you read/write a file on a HDD it will have a seek latency of ~15 ms. If you save a copy of 100 KB for a SATA II drive (300 MB/s), it can save 0.3 ms (less with write caching) which is a small piece of the puzzle. Once you have measured the problem in detail you can come up with a solution, or you could implement the simplest solution and measure it later if you still believe you have a problem to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Use two files. Copy until which line you want into a new file. Add your new line. Then again copy the rest of the lines into the file. Finally, copy the whole content of the new file into the old file

Answer (score 0):

First of all: there is white space in the string you're testing for:

```
String comparison="    return model;";
```

It would be a better idea to compare the lines like this:

```
if (line.trim().equals(comparison.trim())){ ...
```

The call to `trim()` will remove all whitespaces/tabs in the line and the comparison string, so it would match also if some file uses tabs instead of whitespaces, or a different number of whitespaces...